# Date Time change when convert to string issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to subtract minute from my date. BaseDate is my date and `dateMinusMin` is subtract is minuteFrom my date which work completely fine.

```
let baseDate = "2020-03-06 06:00" //My date With format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

let dateMinusMin = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -(240), to: baseDate)!
print(dateMinus4Hours) \\2020-03-06 02:00:00 +0000
```

But when I convert Date to string time is change dramatically and showing `07:30` instead of `02:00`.

```
  let modifyStr = Utill.getLocalStringFromDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z", date: dateMinus4Hours, iden: "en_US_POSIX")
    print(modifyStr) \\ 2020-03-06 07:30 +0530
```

OutPut =  **2020-03-06 07:30 +0530**

Function to convert Date To string

```
 func getLocalStringFromDate(_ currentFormat:String,date:Date,iden:String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = currentFormat
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: iden)
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

Comment: The date does not change, it is displayed in different time zones: "2020-03-06 02:00:00 +0000" is the date in UTC (= GMT+00), and "2020-03-06 07:30 +0530" is the **same date** in the GMT+05:30 time zone.

Comment: I also try with "UTC" but getting same result

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issue in your code. you can see result in below image.

Given Input - 06:00 hours

Output - 02:00 hours (4 hours minus as you want)

[image]

Comment: first output is 20:30:00 +0000 because its UTC. if you convert in your timezone +5:30 then it will 02:00

Comment: I add `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` in my `getLocalStringFromDate ` function and work for me. Thanks